How can I detect and count unique objects in an image using Flutter?
I'm working on a Flutter project where I need to upload an image that contains several objects, some of which are repeated. I want to detect all the objects in the image and return a list that contains the count of each unique object.
Is this possible to achieve using Flutter? If so, what are the steps or tools required to implement this functionality? Any guidance on packages or techniques to use would be greatly appreciated.

What do you mean "objects". Like, just any object? You need an image classifier which can detect anything and also compare them to count?
Seems like a tall order
